# Dropbox npm package is not getting imported properly

Tags: npm, dropbox-api

I am trying a dropbox sample code found [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/guides/getting_started.md).

This is the code that I am using -

```
var dropbox = require("dropbox")

console.log("dropbox:",dropbox)
console.log("dropbox.Client:",dropbox.Client)

var client = new dropbox.Client({
    key: "my-key",
    secret: "my-secret"
});


client.authDriver(new dropbox.AuthDriver.NodeServer(8191));

client.authenticate(function(error, client) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('error')
    return
  }

   console.log("worked")

});
```

But I am getting this error output -

```
Dropbox: function (options) {
  DropboxBase.call(this, options);
}
Dropbox.Client: undefined
/Users/11126/code/node/idea/ideadbapi/idea_bckp/bckp.js:6
var client = new Dropbox.Client({
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/11126/code/node/idea/ideadbapi/idea_bckp/bckp.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Can anyone please help whats going wrong? Why is dropbox.Client undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use the deprecated/un-maintained [dropbox-js library](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js), but it looks like you actually installed the newer [dropbox-sdk-js library](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js).

The latter is preferred anyway, so you should follow that documentation:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js#quickstart